# How to load a javascript chart on the 2nd, 3rd etc. page in JQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am quite new to JQuery Mobile and I've been spending days now to figure out an apparently simple question.

Here's my problem:
I am using a charting javascript library from Amcharts. So far, so good...
What I am trying now is just to create a simple page in JQmobile with let's say 2 links to new pages. All I want is when I click the link, the amchart should display in the div with a specific name.
(Amcharts usually displays the chart in a certain div by calling chart.write('nameofthediv');

So I thought with an event handler bound to $('#container').bind('click', function(){...} I should be able just to include the relevant javascript...

Somehow though...it doesn't work.

Here's the link so you can see what I mean:
http://www.noten-werkstatt.de/jqm_amcharts/

And here is the code from the index.html and the relevant custom-scripting.js.

Thank you very much in advance!

Regards,
Lisa

index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>jQuery Mobile and Amcharts</title>

<link href="amcharts/style.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <!-- Amcharts CSS-File local -->
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> <!-- JQ Mobile CSS-File (CDN) -->


<script src="amcharts/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- Amcharts JS-File local -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- JQ JS-File (CDN) -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- JQ Mobile JS-File (CDN) -->
<script src="custom-scripting.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- Custom Scripting JS-File local -->


</head> 
<body> 

<!-- ****** START PAGE ************ -->
<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Main Page</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#page2" class="page2">Page two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Page three</a></li>
        </ul>      
    </div>
    <div id="chartserialdiv" style="height:500px !important; border: 1px solid;">It's odd...displaying the chart works here (div containr #chartserialdiv)...(Initialized in the window.onload = function() {})<br>But as I want to attach it to a click handler, please click "page two"...
    </div><br>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- ****** 2nd PAGE ************ -->
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page two</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="test">  <!-- ****** DIV CONTAINER "TEST" ************ -->
        If the event handler worked, there must be text after the ":" :<br>      
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="chartserialdiv2" style="height:500px !important; border: 1px solid;"> <!-- ****** DIV CONTAINER "CHARTSERIALDIV" ************ -->
     The is the div container #chartserialdiv2 - Why is the chart not displaying here???
    </div>  
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- ****** 3rd PAGE ************ -->
<div data-role="page" id="page3">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page three</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        As there is no event handler attached to page 3, if you read the text and nothing else happens - that's correct! :-)        
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

custom-scripting.js

```
window.onload = function() {

//This displays the chart on the start page     
var chart;
var dataProvider;       
createChart('chartserialdiv');  
loadCSV("daten/budget_management_projekt_kum.csv");              //DATENQUELLE             

//This is supposed to display the chart on the 2nd page when clicked on the link    
$('#page li a.page2').bind('click', function(event){
    alert("The link \"Page 2\" was clicked...now we turn to page 2 and try to load the chart...");
    $('#test').append("Event Handler-Check: Congratulations, the event handler $(\'#test\').append... worked!!!<br>");

    $('#chartserialdiv2').ready(function(){
        var chart;
        var dataProvider;   
        createChart('chartserialdiv2');  
        loadCSV("daten/budget_management_projekt_kum.csv");              //DATENQUELLE  


    }); 
    //event.preventDefault();
    //return false;

});

$(document).delegate('.ui-page', 'pageshow', function () {
    alert("worked");
            var chart;
        var dataProvider;   
        createChart('chartserialdiv2');  
        loadCSV("daten/budget_management_projekt_kum.csv");              //DATENQUELLE  

});



}


        // method which loads external data
        function loadCSV(file) {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                var request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
            // load
            request.open('GET', file, false);
            request.send();
            parseCSV(request.responseText);
        }

        // method which parses csv data
        function parseCSV(data){ 
            data = data.replace (/,/g,"."); // SUCHE NACH KOMMA UND ERSETZE DURCH PUNKT        
            var rows = data.split("\r");    // SUCHE NACH ZEILENUMBRUCH UND SPALTE DORT ZEILE AB
            dataProvider = [];

            for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++){ // i=1 WEGEN DER ÜBERSCHRIFTEN

                if (rows[i]) {                    

                    var column = rows[i].split(";");  
                    var category = column[0];
                    var value1 = column[1];
                    var value2 = column[2];
                    var value3 = column[3];

                    var dataObject = {category:category, value1:value1, value2:value2, value3:value3};
                    dataProvider.push(dataObject);
                }
            }
            chart.dataProvider = dataProvider;
            chart.validateData();
        }


        function createChart(container){                            // method which creates chart

            chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();       // chart variable is declared in the top


            chart.addTitle('Chart',12, '#FFFFFF', 1, true);
            chart.addLabel(15, 25, 'Mio. €', 'left', 10, '#000000', 0, 1, true);
            chart.backgroundAlpha = 1;
            chart.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
            chart.categoryField = "category";           // here we tell the chart name of category field in our data provider. Wwe called it "date" (look at parseCSV method)

            var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();         // chart must have at least 1 graph
            graph.valueField = "value1";              // graph should know at what field from data provider it should get values.
            graph.lineThickness = 3;
            graph.lineColor = "#336699";
            graph.type = "column";
            graph.bulletAlpha = 1;
            graph.balloonText = "PLAN kum.:[[value]] Mio. €";
            graph.title  = "PLAN kum.";
            graph.fillAlphas = 1;
            chart.addGraph(graph);                      // add graph to the chart

            var graph2 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph2.valueField = "value2"
            graph2.lineThickness = 3;
            graph2.bullet = "bubble";
            graph2.balloonText = "IST kum.:[[value]] Mio. €";
            graph2.title  = "IST kum.";
            graph2.lineColor = "#ff9933";
            chart.addGraph(graph2);

            var graph3 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph3.valueField = "value3";
            graph3.lineThickness = 5;
            graph3.bulletAlpha = 1;
            graph3.lineColor = "#999999";
            graph3.type = "column";
            graph3.fillAlphas = 1;
            graph3.dashLength = 5;
            graph3.balloonText = "Forecast kum.:[[value]] Mio. €";
            graph3.title  = "Forecast kum.";
            chart.addGraph(graph3);

            var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
            chart.addLegend(legend);
            legend.align = "center";
            legend.backgroundAlpha = 1;
            legend.backgroundColor ="#CCCCCC";
            legend.borderAlpha = 1;
            legend.borderColor = "#000000";
            legend.equalWidths =true;
            legend.horizontalGap = 1;
            legend.switchType = "v";
            legend.markerBorderAlpha = 1;
            legend.markerBorderThickness = 1;
            legend.markerBorderColor = "#FFFFFF";
            legend.markerLabelGap = 5;
            legend.position = "bottom";

            // 'chartserialdiv' is id of a container where the chart will be                        
            chart.write(container);


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your code to generate the chart in the [pagshow](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html) event, something like

```
$(document).delegate('#page2', 'pageshow', function( ) { 
      createChart('chartserialdiv2'); 
      loadCSV("daten/budget_management_projekt_kum.csv"); 
});
```